# React render does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hey im a beginner with react and i have an issue

i have this code:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            openModal: false,
            listAmount: 8,
            currentPage: 1,
            buildings: [],
            listRenderd: false,
        }
        this.setModalState = this.setModalState.bind(this)
        this.fetchBuildings = this.fetchBuildings.bind(this);
        this.fetchBuildings();
    }

    fetchBuildings = async () => {
        await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/buildings/get').then(response => {
            var buildings = [];
            Object.values(response.data).flat().map((el, id) => buildings.push(el))
            this.setState({ buildings: this.splitInChunks(buildings, this.state.listAmount) })
        })
    }

    splitInChunks(array, size) {
        var results = [];
        while (array.length) {
          results.push(array.splice(0, size));
        }
        return results;
    };
```

and in my render :

```
<TableContent onClick={console.log(this.state.buildings[this.state.currentPage])} buildings={this.state.buildings[this.state.currentPage]} listAmount={this.state.listAmount} currentPage={this.state.currentPage}/>
```

the console logs :
1 time : undefined
2 time : (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

in my child Class i have

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TableContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buildings: this.props.buildings,
            listAmount: this.props.listAmount,
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        var buildingsElement
            if(this.state.buildings) {
                buildingsElement = this.state.buildings.map((element, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div onClick={console.log(this.state.buildings)} id="table-body-row" className="transition-250ms d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-around align-items-center">
                        <div id="body-row" className="body-row-id text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">{element.id}</div>
                        <div id="body-row" className="body-row-name text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">{element.name}</div>
                        <div id="body-row" className="body-row-hex text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">{`#${element.color_hex}`}</div>
                        <div id="body-row" className="body-row-added text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">{element.created_at.split("T")[0]}</div>
                        <div id="body-row" className="body-row-edited text-white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <div className="d-flex gap-2">
                                <i className="fas fa-edit"></i>
                                <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>)
                })
            }
        return(buildingsElement ? buildingsElement : "Loading...")
    }
}
```

but it always shows "loading..." and the **this.props.buildings** is always undefined if i console log it

what could be wrong? or how can i fix this

Comment: It looks like you're passing *one* "building" to the component: `buildings={this.state.buildings[this.state.currentPage]}`  But then trying to call `.map` on that single instance: `buildingsElement = this.state.buildings.map(`

Comment: Hey david, that does work but the issue is it does not get past the if(this.state.buildings) { in the TableContent class because the props do not get updated after a rerender

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to fix it; I used `this.props.buildings.map` instead of this.state in the `TableContent` class and that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Constructor works only one time. When you try to fetch in constructor it will call it one time and wont wait to fetch response. You can "fetch" in lifecycle that is componentDidMount. Search react class lifecycle and hooks.

```
constructor { ...}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchBuildings();
 }

render(){...}
```